# How do I build a settings panel under the plugin

Tags: plugin-development, options, settings-api

I'm trying to build a settings panel for my plugin that is located under the plugin on the plugin page and slides down when the user clicks the settings link like other plugins (WP Maintenance Mode) do. They look like this:

[image: Screen top]

[image: Screen bot]
I tried to read the plugin code but didn't really understand it because its a bit to complex for me as a beginner. Is this a normal wordpress function or is it extra implemented?

Comment: Please show the code that you have and describe what error/errors are your code generating.

Comment: Also [see the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) and let us know which parts you aren't understanding.